# Access Web Application Data Macro to Sum values in Query and return as variable

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, macros, web-sql

I am working on a small application in Access Services on SharePoint to log colleagues leave requests, and I need to work out a data macro to calculate how many days of leave they have remaining from their allowance.

I have a table [Colleagues] with all of the user data, for simplicity I'll reduce it to [Email] and [Allowance] in days. I have another table which stores the requests [Requests] including the number of days to deduct in each approved leave request [Days Requested].

I have set up a query that returns all approved requests for the colleague and I would like to use a data macro that is triggered to run when the colleague logs in. As you cannot use aggregate functions in Web Applications, I am currently using ForEachRecord in the query to total the number of deductible days, however I cannot work out how to return that to a field in the [Colleague] record.

According to the Access help, I should be able to set the value to a LocalVar and use it in expressions as simply as referencing [Deductible Days], however this is not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I finally worked this out after much tinkering.

In my query I included the [Colleague Email] field as well as the [Days Requested] field, and then when my Application loads it navigates to a form created from the [Colleagues] table. I have modified the Data Source of the form to link the [Email] field in the query results to the [Email] field in the [Colleagues] form.

Following this I was able to create an unbound textbox with the data source =Sum([Days Requested]) referring to the relevant field in the query. Voila! I now have the value to play around with in my application.

Hope that helps, took a lot of fiddling around. No data macros needed after all, but its a method I shall remember in future, opens up a lot of possibilities.

Comment: I thought I had fixed it, but the =Sum expression returns an error when loaded to the web application. Damn Microsoft.

Comment: So it turns out that Access Services simply cannot support aggregate functions. My workaround was to create a SSRS report that loads into the Access form via a browser control. By passing variables through the browser URL and refreshing the report when other fields are updated, you can recreate the aggregate functions. It's a bit of a Sally, I'm afraid, but with the limited systems I can use at work, it's the only workaround I could come up with!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly, I was faced with a very similar problem.

I believe the solution used here will work for you. It involves using a query to Sum up the values (we would use Sum where he used Count), use a Data Macro to run the query and then have have an On Insert/On Update trigger the Data Macro:

http://devspoint.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/validating-data-with-data-macros-in-access-services-2013/

Let me know if this works for you. It worked for me!